# how to customize the number pipe angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to customize the number pipe angular 2
{{ myvar | number:'1.2-2' }} 
for a myvar = 1000
I get 1,000
what I would like is to get 1 000
a space in the place of the , 
any Ideas ?

Comment: The built-in `number` formatter doesn't support that, but the documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html describes writing your own custom pipe

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution from [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript). And it works!

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain pipes. `{{ myvar | number:'1.2-2' | thousand }}` and your thousand pipe can look like this.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'thousand'
})

export class ThousandPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, digits?: string): string {
    if (value) {
      let thousands = value.split(',');
      const preDecimalValue = thousands.pop();
      thousands = thousands.join(' ');
      return thousands + ' ' + preDecimalValue;
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

Presuming that all of the thousands are separated by comma, you will set all thousands in thousands array. In your case, thousands will be `['1']`, and preDecimalValue would be `'000.00'`.